# Guard Malloc causes wacko application behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, guard-malloc

I've got an iOS app where I think memory stomping is happening.  So I turned on Guard Malloc, Guard Edges and Scribble in Xcode and ran it to try to track it down.  But with Guard Malloc enabled, things start to go wrong in really weird ways.  In some (predictable) situations, backgrounds of views won't draw and you can see through to the views behind them.  If I do a file download, the app crashes on the main thread at the end of the download with none of my code on the stack (besides `main`), and there are sometimes some graphics errors logged in the console like:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 201000 bytes for bitmap data
<Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
```

Some of these things (such as `CGBitmapContextInfoCreate`) are not used anywhere in my code.

The last thing logged is something like:

```
Failed to VM allocate 262144 bytes
Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!
```

Has anyone else had Guard Malloc cause these kinds of errors?  What could be the root of this?

Comment: ... are you testing on device?

Comment: @Tommy - No, this is in the simulator.  Guard Malloc is not possible on the device as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Guard Malloc works via the memory management unit (MMU). MMUs allow you to flag certain parts of memory as permitted for access by a process and certain areas as illegal — that's in essence what protected memory is. They do this by dividing memory into individual pages, which are often 4kb, and attributing the relevant permissions to each page. They can't store attributes individually for each address as that'd require huge amounts of storage.

It's the MMU that raises illegal access exceptions.

When running normal code that all means that some out-of-bounds accesses don't raise exceptions because a lot of your data is smaller than 4kb so most of it shares pages with other data. And a write to anywhere in the page is acceptable even if it's not the array you were intending to write to or if the page has been reused by a new object.

So Guard Malloc gives each object an individual page. That hugely pumps up your memory footprint as it rounds all object sizes up to the page size. This is also what kills the performance — any sensible algorithm for caching stops functioning correctly.

A side effect is that there's much less storage to go around. Suppose you have an `NSString` that normally occupies 280 bytes of storage. Well now it occupies an entire page. So you run out of memory a lot more quickly. (EDIT: and as per Greg's comment below, once a page has been allocated, Guard Malloc doesn't allow it to go back into the pool, so your memory footprint becomes cumulative, meaning that you almost certainly eventually run out of memory regardless given that [almost] all objects go on the heap and returning objects is normal)

Guard Edges can exacerbate that situation by putting empty pages in between every allocation. So every object allocated takes at least one extra page out of the virtual memory pool that it otherwise wouldn't have. That can affect you if the virtual pool is sufficiently close in size to your physical pool.

`CGBitmapContextInfoCreate` is almost certainly used internally by one of the standard `UIView`s you're using, when being asked to update its contents. The system no longer has enough memory to satisfy the request, and it looks like the view doesn't attempt to deal with that result gracefully.

Probably the only meaningful advice is to try the debugging tools separately, in isolation.

Comment: I don't believe the guard edge pages consume physical memory.  They certainly consume address space which, in turn, consumes resources in the kernel, but a page that isn't readable or writable doesn't need backing store and the VM subsystem is smart enough to to give it any.

Comment: @bbum you're probably right; they cut holes in the virtual address space — whether that reduces the amount of RAM you can use therefore depends on how much RAM you have versus the virtual pool. Making the extremely safe assumption that the author has a 64bit system it feels very unlikely they have very much physical RAM compared to the virtual address pool. Though one would assume MMUs current can't map the entire 64bit range either, since storage for the mapping is finite?

Comment: Yeah -- the kernel resources are likely fairly minimal, but this is also likely a very suboptimal state.  IIRC, the simulator is just using the system's VM anyway.  The rapidity of consumption is mostly as you describe, but keeping in mind that you have well less than the 4GB of address space to work with in the 23 bit process.  Well less than 2GB, I think.

Comment: The other point about Guard Malloc as currently implemented is that it never frees any memory. Every app will run out of space with Guard Malloc after running long enough.

Comment: @bbum having had a quick glance at my Activity Monitor, iOS Simulator is listed as 'Intel (64 bit)' — I guess they've updated it?

Comment: That may or may not be indicative of the architecture of the running code.   Try an `arch` on an executable compiled for the simulator.

Comment: @bbum You're quite right; binaries built for the simulator are 32-bit.  Which should mean that Guard Edges eats into your total available RAM on any up-to-date computer.